# Creating space separated list that excludes contents of quotes

Tags: java, list

How would I create a list in java that prints `[foo,bar,"lorem ipsum"]` from input of `foo bar "lorem ipsum"` Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, having two lists that find the values then merge them.

```java
            String message = "foo bar "lorem ipsum";
            // Getting the value of the quotes
            List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<String>();
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"")
                    .matcher(message);
            while (m.find()) {
                quotes.add(m.group());
            }
            // Removing quotes from string
            message = message.replaceAll("\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"", "");
            List<String> space = Arrays.asList(message.split("\\s* \\s*"));
            // Merging the lists
            List<String> newList = Stream.concat(space.stream(), quotes.stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            // Printing
            System.out.println(newList);
```